# Is it possible to add values from an array of tuples to separate columns in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to insert new rows into a table from a list of tuples in Postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(col1 TEXT, col2 INT);

INSERT INTO my_table(col1, col2)
SELECT * FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[('a', 0),('b', 0)]);
```

But I'm getting the error:

> ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
> LINE 2:     SELECT * FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[('a', 0),('b', 0)]);

How can I provide a column definition to that query?

The resulting table should look like this:

```
col1 | col2
------------
a    | 0
b    | 0
```

Comment: Remove the brackets enclosing the SELECT and see what happens.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @jarlh removing brackets didnt work

Comment: @CaiusJard ERROR:  INSERT has more target columns than expressions

Comment: What about `INSERT INTO table(col1, col2) values ('a', 0),('b', 0)`?

Comment: @jarlh sometimes we need set the same value for all inserted items, and you could execute `insert into table(col1, same_col) select unnest(array[1,2,3,4,5]), 'same value'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks you want unnest as part of `FROM`:

```
INSERT INTO tab(col1, col2)
SELECT c1, c2
FROM  unnest(ARRAY[('a'::TEXT, 0::INT),('b'::TEXT, 0::INT)]) 
      AS s(c1 TEXT, c2 INT);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=41475c5d16ef51ee5e12797cd75e82c2)**

Comment: What if i was passing in a variable like-
INSERT INTO tab(col1, col2)
SELECT unnest(%(rows)s);

and rows is a python dict like {'a':0,'b':0}

?